# Cannot remove UIActivityIndicator and the view that contains it from screen

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview

I copied the code to show the activity indicator from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363128/ios-activityindicator-over-uitableview-how-to). When I called `hideActivityViewer` nothing happens, and the `activityView` is still there, and the activityIndicator is still spinning. It is as if `hideActivityViewer` does not do anything to the `activityView` at all.

Here is the code I have modified

```
-(void)showActivityViewer
{
    WBAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UIWindow *window = delegate.window;

    _activityView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, window.bounds.size.width, window.bounds.size.height)];
    _activityView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    _activityView.alpha = 0.5;

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityWheel = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(window.bounds.size.width / 2 - 12, window.bounds.size.height / 2 - 12, 24, 24)];
    activityWheel.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite;
    activityWheel.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                                      UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                                      UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
                                      UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);
    [_activityView addSubview:activityWheel];
    [window addSubview: _activityView];

    [[[_activityView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] startAnimating];
}

-(void)hideActivityViewer
{
    NSLog(@"Profile: hiding Activity Viewer");
    [[[_activityView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] stopAnimating];
    [_activityView removeFromSuperview];
    _activityView = nil;
}
```

**Update:**
I'm using the KVO to detect for change in variable and use it to call `showActivityViewer`.
Turns out, `showActivityViewer` was called more than once, as a result there are multiple `activityViewer` on the screen, so when I remove one, the other is still there and I have no to reference to it. I solved this by checking if the `activityView` already exist, and if so don't create a new one.

Comment: How have you declared activityView?

Comment: It could be because `activityView` becomes nil at some point before a call to `hideActivityViewer`. Lets say u call `showActivityViewer` two times, you have two `activityView`s exactly on top of each other and the first one will never be hidden if you call `hideActivityViewer`. Even after matching number of `hideActivityViewer` calls, or more.

Comment: Where are you calling `hideActivityViewer`? Do you see the `NSLog()` results in the console?

Comment: @Rajiv Your hypothesis is correct! I added a if statement to check if activityView exist before creating a new one and it works. Thanks

Comment: now, how do I mark this thing as answered.

Comment: @doog you can't mark comment as answered only upvote , rajiv provided same as an answer so now you can mark it as acceptable one.

Comment: @Balaji ok, answer accepted, just saw that he created an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My comment as an answer:

It could be because `activityView` becomes nil at some point before a call to `hideActivityViewer`. Lets say u call `showActivityViewer` two times consecutively, you have two `activityViews` exactly on top of each other and the first one will never be hidden if you call `hideActivityViewer`. Even after matching number of `hideActivityViewer` calls, or more.

Answer (score 0):

You may be calling ur method "hideActivityViewer" from asynchronous or thread completion blocks.
If so, call ur method on mainthread i.e
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(hideActivityViewer) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];